# Did the Wiimote Strap come in colors other than white and black?

Tags: wiimote

I just got a used Pink Wiimote with Motion Plus Inside, and I saw that it came with a white strap.

Did the straps came in colors other than white and black?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[They did](https://www.siliconera.com/only-japan-gets-colored-wiimote-straps-in-september/), but apparently only in Japan.

[image]